# To carry the most sway

Tags: meaning, expressions, translation

I am not sure how to understand the expression. I'd be happy if someone can explain or even translate into German.

Except from the book:

> The first way is indisputable: of all the social scientists,
>   economists carry the most sway when it comes to influencing public
>   policy.

Answer (score 1):

**The first way is indisputable** - you can't challenge it, there's no dispute possible here for example "the earth is round" is indisputable.

**of all the social scientists, economists carry the most sway when it comes to influencing public policy.** - I could re-write this to something like:

"Out of every type of social scientist, the economist has the most influence on public policy."

To carry the most sway means to have the most influence on something.

Influencing public policy means to change and have your opinion matter on social laws.